How to attach pdf document to azure devops work item?
I tried to attach pdf document to azure devops work item, it shows 400(Bad Request) error.
For your information attach textfile is working as expected, but I am not sure what is the best approach to attach a pdf document.
Here is my attach function.
export const addPdfAttachmentToWorkItem = async (
  workItemId: number,
  pat: string,
  organizationUrl: string,
  projectId: string,
  pdfBlob: Blob,
  fileName: string
) => {
  try {
    const encodedPat = btoa(`:${pat}`)
    const url = `${organizationUrl}/${projectId}/_apis/wit/attachments?api-version=6.0&fileName=${fileName}&uploadType=simple`
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', pdfBlob, fileName);
    const attachRes = await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url,
      data: formData,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${encodedPat}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
      },
    })

    const witUrl = `${organizationUrl}/${projectId}/_apis/wit/workitems/${workItemId}?api-version=6.0`
    const workItemData = [
      {
        op: 'add',
        path: `/relations/-`,
        value: {
          rel: 'AttachedFile',
          url: attachRes.data.url,
          attributes: {
            comment: `Attached work package report for WIT ${workItemId}`,
          },
        },
      },
    ]
    const response = await axios.patch(witUrl, workItemData, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${encodedPat}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json',
      },
      params: {
        $expand: 'all',
      },
    })
    return response.data
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error updating work item:', error)
    throw error
  }
}

And then, here is the error message I got.


Can you try to convert the pdf file content as base64 format(e.g. btoa(formData)) and input to the file upload file API? Then you can change application/pdf to application/json and check if it can make some changes.

I tried to conevrt them to base64 but it shows same error. Here are the code snippets.
    const pdfBase64 = await convertBlobToBase64(pdfBlob);
    const attachRes = await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url,
      data: pdfBase64,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${encodedPat}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })


Hi @SmartSolutions Could you confirm whether your requirement is to attach pdf file to work item like this https://i.imgur.com/fJ5H5nH.png?

@Sridevi your image link is not working. Can you please send me again?

Could you try switching your network to mobile and confirm if you are able to see images in answer or not?

Hi @SmartSolutions any update on the issue?

To attach pdf document to Azure DevOps work item, I used below sample code with application/octet-stream as Content type:
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');

const addPdfAttachmentToWorkItem = async (
  workItemId,
  pat,
  organizationUrl,
  projectId,
  filePath,
  fileName
) => {
  try {
    const pdfBuffer = fs.readFileSync(filePath);

    const encodedPat = Buffer.from(`:${pat}`).toString('base64');
    const uploadUrl = `${organizationUrl}/${projectId}/_apis/wit/attachments?api-version=6.0&fileName=${fileName}&uploadType=simple`;

    const attachRes = await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: uploadUrl,
      data: pdfBuffer,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${encodedPat}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream', 
      },
    });

    const attachmentUrl = attachRes.data.url;

    const workItemUrl = `${organizationUrl}/${projectId}/_apis/wit/workitems/${workItemId}?api-version=6.0`;

    const workItemData = [
      {
        op: 'add',
        path: '/relations/-',
        value: {
          rel: 'AttachedFile',
          url: attachmentUrl,
          attributes: {
            comment: `Attached PDF document to work item ${workItemId}`,
          },
        },
      },
    ];

    const response = await axios.patch(workItemUrl, workItemData, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${encodedPat}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json',
      },
    });

    console.log('Attachment added successfully:', response.data);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error attaching file to work item:', error.response?.data || error.message);
    throw error;
  }
};

(async () => {
  const workItemId = 1;
  const pat = 'pat_token_here';
  const organizationUrl = 'https://dev.azure.com/orgname';
  const projectId = 'projname';
  const filePath = 'C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\AI900Cert.pdf'; 
  const fileName = 'AI900Cert.pdf'; 

  await addPdfAttachmentToWorkItem(workItemId, pat, organizationUrl, projectId, filePath, fileName);
})();

Response:

To confirm that, I checked the same in Azure DevOps Portal where pdf added successfully as attachment like his:


Is there a way to upload pdf Blob object directly to azure devops? Instead of attach local files because the Blob file was downloaded data from another api.

Hi @SmartSolutions Could you please post a new question for uploading pdf blob object to Azure DevOps and share the link here as Blob storage will be new requirement?

I posted a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79038774/how-to-attach-base64-or-blob-filepdf-to-azure-devops-work-item
Please check and help me out to solve this challenge.
