How to attach base64 or blob file(PDF) to azure devops work item?
I tried to attach pdf document to azure devops work item, but it shows following Error in screenshot.
I can't get the pdf file from local because the PDF blob is downloaded file from cloud.

For your information attach textfile is working as expected, but I am not sure what is the best approach to attach a pdf document.
Here is my attach function.

const convertBlobToBase64 = (blob: Blob): Promise<string> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      const base64data = reader.result?.toString().split(',')[1]
      resolve(base64data || '')
    }
    reader.onerror = reject
  })
}

export const addPdfAttachmentToWorkItem = async (
  workItemId: number,
  pat: string,
  organizationUrl: string,
  projectId: string,
  pdfBlob: Blob,
  fileName: string
) => {
  try {
    const encodedPat = btoa(`:${pat}`)
    const url = `${organizationUrl}/${projectId}/_apis/wit/attachments?api-version=6.0&fileName=${fileName}&uploadType=simple`
    const pdfBase64 = await convertBlobToBase64(pdfBlob)
    const attachRes = await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url,
      data: pdfBase64,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${encodedPat}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
      },
    })

    const witUrl = `${organizationUrl}/${projectId}/_apis/wit/workitems/${workItemId}?api-version=6.0`
    const workItemData = [
      {
        op: 'add',
        path: `/relations/-`,
        value: {
          rel: 'AttachedFile',
          url: attachRes.data.url,
          attributes: {
            comment: `Attached work package report for WIT ${workItemId}`,
          },
        },
      },
    ]
    const response = await axios.patch(witUrl, workItemData, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${encodedPat}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json',
      },
      params: {
        $expand: 'all',
      },
    })
    return response.data
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error updating work item:', error)
    throw error
  }
}



I can't get the pdf file from local because the PDF blob is downloaded file from cloud.

It's not supported to upload pdf Blob object directly to azure devops, you need to download the file to local and then to upload. To upload local pdf to devops work item, please refer to your original ticket.
Edit:
If you would like to upload base64 pdf file, you can check below script:
const fs = require('fs');
const axios = require('axios');

const addPdfAttachmentToWorkItem = async (
  workItemId,
  pat,
  organizationUrl,
  projectId,
  filePath,
  fileName
) => {
  try {
    const pdfBuffer = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
    const pdfBase64 = pdfBuffer.toString('base64');

    const encodedPat = Buffer.from(`:${pat}`).toString('base64');
    const uploadUrl = `${organizationUrl}/${projectId}/_apis/wit/attachments?api-version=6.0&fileName=${fileName}&uploadType=simple`;

    const attachRes = await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: uploadUrl,
      data: pdfBase64,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${encodedPat}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'base64',
      },
    });

    const attachmentUrl = attachRes.data.url;

    const workItemUrl = `${organizationUrl}/${projectId}/_apis/wit/workitems/${workItemId}?api-version=6.0`;

    const workItemData = [
      {
        op: 'add',
        path: '/relations/-',
        value: {
          rel: 'AttachedFile',
          url: attachmentUrl,
          attributes: {
            comment: `Attached PDF document to work item ${workItemId}`,
          },
        },
      },
    ];

    const response = await axios.patch(workItemUrl, workItemData, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${encodedPat}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json',
      },
    });

    console.log('Attachment added successfully:', response.data);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error attaching file to work item:', error.response?.data || error.message);
    throw error;
  }
};

(async () => {
  const workItemId = 3321;
  const pat = 'PAT';
  const organizationUrl = 'https://dev.azure.com/org';
  const projectId = 'projectname';
  const filePath = 'C:\\Users\\wade\\test.pdf'; 
  const fileName = 'test.pdf'; 

  await addPdfAttachmentToWorkItem(workItemId, pat, organizationUrl, projectId, filePath, fileName);
})();





Azure Devops supports to upload a file in base64 format. Is there a way to upload base64 pdf file correctly? @wade zhou - MSFT

@SmartSolutions, we can convert the file to base64 and upload to work item, i will add the script above.

Since the file is downloaded blob data, I can't get the local uri

@SmartSolutions, the script is uploading pdf from local as base64 format. As i mentioned, it's not supported to upload pdf from blob data directly to work item. Regarding downloading pdf from blob data and get local uri, it could be another topic which i'm not familiar. You can raise a new ticket to get the details. Thanks.
